# Images do not render correctly in WPF ribbon control

Tags: c#, wpf, image, ribbon

I just purchased some image collections for use with the WPF Ribbon control. The images are immaculate; however, they do not render correctly in the control.

[image: Ribbon Screen Shot]

Neither the small or large images are not rendered correctly. I've tried different image sizes but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

I have an array of different image sizes available. Here's a snippet of my XAML.

```xml
<RibbonTab Header="Edit">
    <RibbonGroup Header="Clipboard">
         <RibbonButton Label="Paste" LargeImageSource="Images\paste.png" ToolTipFooterTitle="" ToolTipImageSource="Images/paste_sm.png" ToolTipTitle="Paste" ToolTipDescription="Insert text from the clipboard at the current location"></RibbonButton>
         <RibbonButton Label="Cut" SmallImageSource="Images\cut_sm.png" ToolTipDescription="Cut the selected text" ToolTipTitle="Cut" ToolTipImageSource="Images/cut.png"></RibbonButton>
         <RibbonButton Label="Copy" SmallImageSource="Images\copy_sm.png" ToolTipDescription="Copy the selected text" ToolTipTitle="Copy" ToolTipImageSource="Images/copy.png"></RibbonButton>
         <RibbonButton Label="Select All" ToolTipDescription="Select all text in document" ToolTipTitle="Select All"></RibbonButton>
     </RibbonGroup>
</RibbonTab>
```

I'm new to WPF and am amazed that I have to struggle with issues like this.

Does anyone know how to make my images render correctly?

Comment: What is the size of `Images\paste.png`?

Comment: As indicated in the question, I have tried different sizes, included 32x32 and 64x64.

Comment: I mentioned exact file (Images\paste.png) and there is nosize mention ("different" is not a size).

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: It can be any size. I am trying to figure out how to make it appear without resizing artifacts.

Comment: It can't be any size, if you have specified `LargeImageSource` it should be 32x32 at 96dpi.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: Well, that was the first size I tried. (The image files don't appear to specify DPI.) One thing is that I'm testing on a laptop with an extremely high resolution and Window is doing some things in the background so everything doesn't appear super tiny. So maybe the 32x32 buttons in the ribbon are not going to display at 32x32. (However I just tested and making everything tiny (100%) doesn't seem to matter either.

Comment: `The image files don't appear to specify DPI` But `LargeImageSource` should be 32x32 at 96 DPI display.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: BTW, that's another thing that really irritates me. If I design my software to look good on 96 DPI displays, does that mean I need to write another version of my software to run on other tyes of displays? Saying the image needs to be this size for this type of display seems to ignore the possibility that I'd like my software to run on many systems, even if they have different display settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a few different options for [`RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.bitmapscalingmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on the RibbonButtons. I've found that sometimes `NearestNeighbor` works better. `UseLayoutRounding="True"` may help as well.

Comment: `RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode` doesn't seem to make any difference at all. `UseLayoutRounding` does affect the output; however, it still doesn't display the image correctly. It still has irregularities. Aside from the fact, of course, that it seems a terrible design to have to specify this for each button even if it did work. I'm new to WPF and I'm definitely not impressed. Here, I was expecting information that my large icons should be this size and my small ones should be that size. But things can never be that easy when it comes to WPF.

Comment: You could use a style and not have to declare it for every button, but anyways, what does the original image look like, I assume you are scaling it down?

Comment: The original images look something like [this](http://axialis.com/stock-icons/pure-flat-2013-total-snapshot-48.html). I have an array of sizes available, and could resize them myself. I am skilled in creating graphic images. So ultimately I do not want to them scale. I want them to appear as good as they look in their original form.

Comment: It may be related to DPI, it looks like, based on the font size, that you are on a high DPI display. See http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BeAwareOfDPIWithImagePNGsInWPFImagesScaleWeirdOrAreBlurry.aspx

Comment: I did see that article before. I will look a little closer and try to run some tests. Thanks.